# Basic design of low-wattage 5V battery charger (is this realistic?)

Tags: battery-charging, gps

I'm trying to come up with a solution for keeping a very small GPS tracker mounted someplace where it will stay indefinitely without an external power source. Since my main interest will be using such a thing on my vehicles in case of theft, one possible way it could be self-powered would be through kinetic energy.

I'm thinking I might be able to make a 'shake flashlight' style dynamo - a rod on a shaft which moves past copper coils as it bounces up and down. I know it'll work to generate electricity, I'm just not sure how much will be enough to realistically charge a ~3-5v lithium battery. All I know is my 18650 battery charger says it supplies them with 4.2V DC at 750mA.

As for a GPS receiver chipset with GSM rx/tx, it requires very little power when set to connect only a few times per day and send its location. Even the smallest GPS trackers you see on eBay claim about 2 weeks battery life with just their built-in 400 mAh battery. So, if I can make this work, I believe that on a bicycle, motorcycle, etc., as long as it's being ridden it should be able to keep enough of a charge. Forever. In theory.

So, please, tell me why nobody else has done this.. Would it just be too much trouble to convert a trickle of microwatts into ~3 watts, over time?

Comment: Have you considered charging the GPS battery from the vehicle electrical system when the engine is running?  I think that would be simpler and more reliable than your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it sounds feasible to me.

If a 400mAh battery last two weeks, it means that the circuit consumes about 4.3mW on average (400mAh * 3.6V / (2 wks * 7 days * 24 hours)) . Let's say that your shake-based generator will work 30 minutes per day, then it would have to generate about 206mW when active (24 hours/ 0.5 hour * 4.3mW). On top of that I would add about 20% extra to account for inefficiencies of the power conversion circuitry (generator power conditioning + battery charging), what translates into a requirement of 250mW of output power from the generator when it's active.

My next step would be to research generators that can actually deliver these 250mW on average in realistic driving/riding conditions. It will probably be a trade off between size and output power. Considerations in terms of how smooth the driving/riding are will also be important.